# Defining type and property of that type inside the class

Tags: c#, class, types, properties, naming

There is a problem to name property and type. Example:

```
public class A
{
    public class B { ... }
    public B B; // << error
}
```

### Question 1: Why error?

I could solve it like this

```
public class A
{
    public B B;
}
public class B { ... } // move it outside
```

or like this

```
public class A
{
    public class B { ... }
    public B BB; // rename property
}
```

or even

```
public class A
{
    public class BB { ... } // rename type
    public BB B;
}
```

### Question 2: How would you do it?

---

Moving type declaration outside is risky, because there could be several classes what semantically need *same name* for the type -> conflict -> strange names for some classes types or necessity to put classes inside namespaces.

Renaming it.. tricky. To example, renaming `Shape` type, which has to be declared for several classes drawing figures: `FigureLine`, `FigurePoint`, etc. I could call them `ShapeLine`, `ShapePoint` and so on. Or I could rename type `Shape` to be something like

```
public class FigureLine
{
    public enum LineShape {Straight, Bend, Whatever};
    public LineShape Shape {get; private set;}
}
```

but now if I try to use it, then it become `FigureLine.LineShape` - that double *Line* is not nice.

Renaming property... How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Solve it by moving it outside. I'd recommend following the principle that all non-private types should be in their own source file.

2 - I'm less clear what the problem is here, even by moving the enum to its own file, I'd stick with your names:

```
public enum LineShape {Straight, Bend, Whatever};

public class FigureLine
{
    public LineShape Shape {get; private set;}
}
```

`LineShape`is a better name than just `Shape` as it better describes what the enum is for (defining line styles, rather than eg 2D or 3D shapes).

Comment: Simply.. amazing. Thanks, this solves all issues (naming is nice, there will be no conflicts, there is no duplicating `Line` when referencing either property or type)!

Comment: To summarize - solution is to move the type outside and to rename it (to be more bound to related class).

Answer (score 3):

> Question 1: Why error?

You've got two members both called `B` within the same class. (A type is a member too.) You can't do that, aside from method overloading.

From section 10.3 of the C# spec:

> - The names of constants, fields, properties, events, or types must differ from the names of all other members declared in the same class.

Next:

> Question 2: How would you do it?

If you want the class to be public, I'd probably make it a top-level class instead.

Comment: Why they must differ? Someone said "let it be so" or are there reasons behind? What is "aside from method overloading"? Can I overload something to have `public Shape Shape {get; set;}` with `Shape` declaration inside class?

Comment: It makes sense when you think about it.  If I say A.B, would I mean B the type or B the property?  Just my preference, but I do not like nested classes anyways.  I would much prefer to use a unique namespace to keep the related classes in their own "sandbox".

Comment: @Sinatr: No, you can't do that as it's a property, so it would still violate the constraint I listed. As for why it's the case - I suspect it makes all kinds of things simpler.#

Comment: @JamesR., I don't really care how hard is it for compiler/intellisence to get things right. I only care about myself ^^. While `A.B` seems confusing at first, there are still many ways to understand what exactly it means. Maybe example of when things really get "confusing" even for myself would be sufficient. Otherwise I am prone to think, what it's a bug =D

Comment: @Sinatr: It's clearly not a **bug** - it's working according to the specification. You may think it was a poor design decision, but then I'd just disagree in general. Having a particular name mean exactly one thing is a useful property, IMO.